# Count items occurrence in a list given other items

Tags: python

I have written the following python code to parse .csv files and print two columns, date and rating. Now I want to count ratings according to date for example if `2018-4-01` occur 4 times with rating `1,4,1,4` I want to print

```
2018-4-01 1 2
2018-4-01 4 2
```

the code I have tried

```
import glob
import csv
import re
from collections import Counter
path = "ReviewsSep2018/*.csv"
mylist = []
    for filename in glob.glob(path):
    print(filename)
    with open(filename, newline='', encoding='utf-16') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            result = re.search(r'\d+\W\d+\W\d+', row[5])
            if result:
                line = result.group()
                mylist.append(tuple([line,row[9]]))
        print(mylist)
for i in mylist:
    print(i[0],i[1])
```

the output of the code example

```
2018-09-01 1
2018-09-01 5
2018-09-01 2
2018-09-01 1
2018-08-23 1
2018-09-01 4
2018-09-01 4
2018-09-01 5
2018-09-01 2
2018-09-02 1
2018-09-02 5
2018-09-02 5
```

desired result

```
date       star   count
2018-09-01   1        2
2018-09-01   2        3
2018-09-01   5        2
2018-09-02   5        2
2018-08-23   1        1
```

Comment: Consider using a dictionary like myDictionary['date and rating as a string']=count

Comment: Please provide a sample of input data

Comment: `collections.Counter` will help you: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turn your `mylist` into `Counter`

```
mycount = Counter()
```

Instead of appending to the list increment count of `(date, rating)` tuple:

```
mycount[(line,row[9])] += 1
```

And finally, display it with:

```
for (date, rating), count in mycount.items():
    print(date, rating, count)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using the pandas library you can use `groupby` once you have parsed the data. Also in my opinion pandas has a good `.csv` reading functionality.

```
import pandas as pd

(pd.DataFrame([['2018-09-01', 1],
              ['2018-09-01', 5],
              ['2018-09-01', 2],
              ['2018-09-01', 1],
              ['2018-08-23', 1],
              ['2018-09-01', 4],
              ['2018-09-01', 4],
              ['2018-09-01', 5],
              ['2018-09-01', 2],
              ['2018-09-02', 1],
              ['2018-09-02', 5],
              ['2018-09-02', 5]],
             columns=['date', 'star']
            )
 .assign(count=1)
 .groupby(['date', 'star'])
 .count()
)
```